# Subtract two DateTime fields in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I subtract two different formats for DateTime field to get the difference of days and time between them.

My models:

```
class TimeAnswerElement(models.Model):
    costumer_time = models.DateTimeField()
    my_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_compartment = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My views:

```
object = get_object_or_404(TimeAnswerElement, id=1)
time_compartment = object.my_time - object.costumer_time 
#My data for fields
#object.my_time = 2020-04-28 19:31:35.550655+00:00
#object.costumer_time = 2020-04-28 11:11:00
```

My solution returns an error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the lack of a timezone value in `costumer_time` could be causing it to deserialize into a string instead of a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you have the issue but you can solve it by checking if they are instance of datetime and else co'vert them:

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser
if not isinstance (object.my_time, datetime.datetime):
    my_time=parser.parse(object.my_time)
if not isinstance (object.costumer_time, datetime.datetime):
    costumer_time=parser.parse(object.costumer_time)

time_compartment = my_time - costumer_time
```